# bootstrap text align to left

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've the following code and I need to align my text to left

```
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2 oper-label" })
```

when I do it like following its working and text align to left.

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .form-horizontal .control-label {
    text-align: left;
  }
}
```

But when I try to do it in the second class its not working

```
.oper-label {
    font-weight: normal;
    text-align: left;
}
```

My question is the following

> 1. why the second option is not working?
> 2. does the first option which is work is the right way to do it,maybe there is  better way to do that...
> 3. when the text is align to left now in some labels and textboxes there is much spaces  if I want that the label and the text box will be
>      closer how can I do that ?

Edit,

The html code is below

```
<label class="control-label col-md-2 operation-label" for="Name"> Name</label>


    <div class="col-md-10">
                    <input class="text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-length-max="30" data-val-regex="Invalid Provider Name" data-val-required="Name field is required." id="ExternalName" name="Name" type="text" value="">
                    <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="Name" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
                </div>
```

Comment: Please post the generated HTML, not your code to generate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **!important**:

```
.oper-label {
    font-weight: normal;
    text-align: left !important;
}
```

But as a general recommendation when using front-end frameworks (such as Bootstrap and Foundation), always make sure that your custom CSS rules come after bootstrap or foundation CSS rules (when linking the stylesheet files inside the page ). This way, you can override their styles as needed.

Once you do that, you can simply declare:

```
.control-label.oper-label {
    font-weight: normal;
    text-align: left;
}
```

As for the spacing issue between textboxes and *left-aligned* labels, you can either add a `.col-xs-1` class to your `.control-label` or override bootstrap's fixed-width labels and set a custom percentage width for the `.control-label`:

```
.form-horizontal .control-label { width: 25%; }
```

Comment: Thanks Khalid,1+,Just the last issue was not solved when I use the { width: 25%; } like you tell the label become on top the text box,maybe you have another idea how to solve it...

Comment: If you'd like to go for the percentage option and avoid label/textbox overlapping, just add the following CSS override rule .form-group > div { margin-left: 25%; }